# SharePoint web-parts as tabs : Calendar entries are showing up at the top

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I've used HillbillyTabs jQuery code to have all the webparts in to tabs. All of my webparts are Calenders, the events in the each tabs are showing up at the top, once I click view more they are showing up as expected.

So, I tried to increase the Timeout to 900 from 300. This did not do the trick, I've read from other

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    setTimeout(function() {

        HillbillyTabs(["Calendar 1","Calendar 2","Calendar 3", "Calendar 4"]);

    }, 1000);

});
```

I expect the calendar entries to display in each tabs section, instead of having to click view-more in each tab.

Here is the link to full code.

http://www.markrackley.net/2014/11/25/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs2-0/

[Click here to see how Calendar entries looks now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtamZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is my test result with code snippet below:

```
<!-- Reference the jQueryUI theme's stylesheet on the Google CDN. Here we're using the "Start" theme --> 
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<!-- Reference jQuery on the Google CDN --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Reference jQueryUI on the Google CDN --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


        //Put 3 web parts in 3 different tabs
//        var webPartTitles = ["Web Part Title 1","Web Part Title 2","Web Part Title 3"];
//        HillbillyTabs(webPartTitles);

        //Create a Tab with Two Web Parts, and a second tab with one Web Part
//        var webPartTitles = ["Tab Title;#Web Part Title 1;#Web Part Title 2","Web Part Title 3"];
//        HillbillyTabs(webPartTitles);

        //Put all web parts (that have visible titles) on page that have into tabs 
        setTimeout(function() {

            HillbillyTabs(["mycal1","mycal2","mycal3"]);

        }, 1000);


    });


    function HillbillyTabs(webPartTitles)
    {
        if(webPartTitles == undefined)
        {
            var CEWPID = "";
            $("#tabsContainer").closest("div [id^='MSOZoneCell_WebPart']").find("span[id^='WebPartCaptionWPQ']").each(function()
            {
                CEWPID = $(this).attr("id");
            });

            var index = 0;
            $("span[id^='WebPartCaptionWPQ']").each(function()
            {
                if($(this).attr("id") != CEWPID)
                {
                    var title = $(this).prev("span").text();

                    $("#HillbillyTabs").append('<li><a href="#Tab'+index+'" id="TabHead'+index+'" onclick="HillbillyTabClick(this.id);">'+
                        title+'</a></li>').after('<div id="Tab'+index+'"></div>');

                    var webPart = $(this).prev("span").hide().closest("span").closest("[id^='MSOZoneCell_WebPart']");

                    $("#Tab" + index).append((webPart));
                    index++;
                }
            });
        } else {
        for(index in webPartTitles)
            {
                var title = webPartTitles[index];
                var tabContent = title.split(";#");
                if (tabContent.length > 1)
                {
                    $("#HillbillyTabs").append('<li><a href="#Tab'+index+'" id="TabHead'+index+'" onclick="HillbillyTabClick(this.id);">'+
                        tabContent[0]+'</a></li>').after('<div id="Tab'+index+'"></div>');

                    for(i = 1; i < tabContent.length; i++)
                    {
                        $("span[id^='WebPartCaptionWPQ']").each(function()
                        {
                            $(this).prev("span:contains('"+tabContent[i]+"')").each(function()
                            {
                                 if ($(this).text() == tabContent[i]){

                                    var webPart = $(this).closest("span").closest("[id^='MSOZoneCell_WebPart']");

                                    $("#Tab" + index).append((webPart));
                                 }

                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $("span[id^='WebPartCaptionWPQ']").each(function()
                    {
                        $(this).prev("span:contains('"+title+"')").each(function()
                        {
                             if ($(this).text() == title){
                                $("#HillbillyTabs").append('<li><a href="#Tab'+index+'" id="TabHead'+index+'" onclick="HillbillyTabClick(this.id);">'+
                                    title+'</a></li>').after('<div id="Tab'+index+'"></div>');

                                var webPart = $(this).hide().closest("span").closest("[id^='MSOZoneCell_WebPart']");

                                $("#Tab" + index).append((webPart));
                             }

                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        $("#tabsContainer").tabs();

        ShowActiveTab();

    }


    function HillbillyTabClick(id)
    {
        $.cookie("ActiveTab",id,{ path: '/' });
    }

    function ShowActiveTab()
    {
        $("#" + $.cookie("ActiveTab")).click();
    }

</script>
<div id="tabsContainer"><ul id="HillbillyTabs"></ul></div>
```

Event entry display as expected in each calendar tab:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please see the same question I have answered in Technet ealier today:

[SharePoint web-parts as tabs : Calendar entries are showing up at the top](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c3e548ef-104e-4b8c-91ba-12a7dfada82a/sharepoint-webparts-as-tabs-calendar-entries-are-showing-up-at-the-top?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: I posted the same in Technet, that was me, I replied to you there.

Comment: Let's talk in Technet.